# why vite build and npm serve not working together?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, serve

I recently migrated from CRA to VITE. But I am running into a serve issue.

I build my app by running  `vite build` . and to serve it I use  `Vite serve`  and everything works just fine.

Tho, I need to be using npm's  `serve`  command. Whenever I run  `vite build`  and then try npm's  `serve /dist/`
it gives me a bunch of Failed to fetch dynamically imported module.

I see that it is trying to find the entry.js files from http://localhost:3000/my-component.entry.js

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In general, **Vite** and **npm serve** are not designed to work together.

**Vite** provides its own development server. This server is optimized for development workflows.

**npm serve** is used to serve the static files that result from a build. It is designed for production environments.